# Will The Application Devloped On .NET Framework Will Work On .NET Core

Tags: .net

I Have Installed Latest .NET Core Sdk On My Ubuntu 20.04. 3 LTS
[Dotnet Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Uyis.png)
Using Below Method

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

```
sudo apt-get update; \
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0
```

I Have An Microsoft Indic Input Tool File Named As Hindi.exe Which Is Devloped Upon .NET Framework I Have Downloaded It From This Website
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/bhashaindia/downloads.aspx

Now When I Try To Install Hindi.exe I Get This Error[Installation Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6z9P.png) Instead I Have Installed The .NET Core Sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.NET applications** developed on **.NET5.0** can run on some **Ubutu** versions like ***(16.04, 18.04, 20.04, 21.04)***, if your .NET application has been developed in a lower framework version then probably you need to migrate to .NET5 before install it on Ubuntu.

To install .NET 5 on Ubuntu follow next steps:

1.- Open a shell in Ubuntu and install the Microsoft package repository using the following commands.

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

2.- Install the latest .NET5 SDK.

```
sudo apt-get update; \
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0
```

3.- Verify version

```
dotnet --version
```

Comment: okay please tell me how should i install framework 5 in ubuntu

Comment: There's no such thing as "framework 5.0". The terminology is just ".NET 5.0" and ".NET 6.0". The .NET Framework is the Windows-only implementation, currently (and likely to be permanently) 4.8.

Comment: @AdityaKirad I added the steps to install .NET 5 on my answer

Comment: Please See  Again My Question I Have Edited  It  And  Open The Link  I Have Given In My Question Whether Its  For  Picture Or  For  A  Site